# References to hash insideanother hash give Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string

Tags: perl

I have an object `$burStageStats` that I fill with data.

```
my $additional_event_details = {
                        'status'     => '\N',
                        'duration'   => '\N',
                        'keyword'    => $keyword
            };
            my $statsHash = {
                        'time'   => '\N',
                        'event_type'     => 'INFO',
                        'backup_stage'   => '\N',
                        'additional_event_details'    => $additional_event_details
            };
            push (@burStageStats, $statsHash);
```

Later I loop through and print the values to a BCP file

```
foreach my $backup (@{$burStageStats}) {
    foreach my $backupStage ($backup) {
        print BCP "$siteId\t" . $backupStage->{'time'} . "\t" .
                  $backupStage->{'event_type'} . "\t" .
                  $stageIdMap->{$backupStage->{'additional_event_details'}->{'backup_stage'}} . "\n";
    }
}
```

I get the following error

> Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /data/ddp/current/analysis/TOR/bur/parseburLog line 180,  line 11287.

Which I imagine points to the way I reference in the line

```
              $stageIdMap->{$backupStage->{'additional_event_details'}->{'backup_stage'}} . "\t" .
```

But I am not sure how to write that line properly. The code works but I would like less errors reported obviously.

Comment: are you using strict and warnings?

Comment: yes using both for this

Comment: Just like your previous question, you have failed to demonstrate your problem. If you can't even describe the problem, how could you hope to fix it? Please see [mcve] for how to do this.

Comment: why are you using `@{$burStageStats}` and not directly `@burStageStats`  in your foreach loop?

Answer (score 2):

The warning tells us that `$backupStage->{'additional_event_details'}->{'backup_stage'}` returns a value which does not exist in the hash referenced by `$stageIdMap`.  e.g., If `$backupStage->{'additional_event_details'}->{'backup_stage'}` is 'foo', then `$stageIdMap->{'foo'}` is missing or undefined.

Given the example data at the top of your question, I note that `$backupStage->{'additional_event_details'}->{'backup_stage'}` does not exist in that example data - the `$additional_event_details` hash doesn't include a `backup_stage` key.  `backup_stage` is in `$statsHash`, not `$backupStage->{'additional_event_details'}`.  This seems likely to be the root problem, as there's a very good chance that `$stageIdMap->{undef}` (for an actual `undef`, not the string 'undef') doesn't exist.

If you were to provide a short, self-contained example program which we can run for ourselves to see the problem in action, then we would be able to provide more definite (and probably more useful) assistance.